# Mixing vboxmanage and bash commands in perl script

Tags: linux, perl, bash, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox on Ubuntu 12.04 to run virtual machines. I'm trying to execute a VirtualBox command through the CLI, using VBoxManage. I want to capture its output in a text file, so I've written the following:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp;

my $vmname = <STDIN>;

system("vboxmanage showvminfo $vmname | > vminfo.txt");
my @vminfo = read_file('vminfo.txt');
print @vminfo;
```

However, nothing happens. When I open vminfo.txt it is empty. It should contain a lot of info about the VM.

Is it even possible to submit commands like this? I am aware that there could be problems with having vboxmanage as the prefix. Is there a way I can escape that command and submit a bash command on the same line?

Thanks.

Comment: You are both pipe:ing and redirecting output - `system("vboxmanage showvminfo $vmname > vminfo.txt");` should work.

Comment: @Anders - That was the original approach I took, but that didn't work as it turns out vboxmanage doesn't allow redirecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to redirect to a file:

```
chomp( my @vminfo = `vboxmanage showvminfo $vmname` );
```